# How to replace all dates in datatime64[ns] column to 1 in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a Dataframe, df, with the following column

#### Input Data

```py
df['Sent']=
2019-02-11 11:10:01.000
2019-02-18 11:45:01.000
2019-02-25 12:20:00.995
2019-03-04 12:55:00.995
2019-03-11 13:30:00.995
2020-08-07 10:48:08.000
2020-08-11 14:20:13.720
2020-08-15 17:52:20.000
2020-08-18 09:24:26.000
2020-08-22 12:56:31.615
```

Here type of the column is **datetime64[ns]**. I want to replace all dates with 01.

#### Expected Output

```py
2019-02-01 11:10:01.000
2019-02-01 11:45:01.000
2019-02-01 12:20:00.995
2019-03-01 12:55:00.995
2019-03-01 13:30:00.995
2020-08-01 10:48:08.000
2020-08-01 14:20:13.720
2020-08-01 17:52:20.000
2020-08-01 09:24:26.000
2020-08-01 12:56:31.615
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? What errors are you running into?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
```

You can make use of [`pd.tseries.offsets.MonthBegin()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.tseries.offsets.MonthBegin.html) method:-

```
df['Sent']=df['Sent']-pd.tseries.offsets.MonthBegin()
```

Now if you print `df['Sent']` you will get your desired output:-

```
0   2019-02-01 11:10:01.000
1   2019-02-01 11:45:01.000
2   2019-02-01 12:20:00.995
3   2019-03-01 12:55:00.995
4   2019-03-01 13:30:00.995
5   2020-08-01 10:48:08.000
6   2020-08-01 14:20:13.720
7   2020-08-01 17:52:20.000
8   2020-08-01 09:24:26.000
9   2020-08-01 12:56:31.615
Name: Sent, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just [pandas.Timestamp.replace()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.replace.html) is enough.

```py
df['Sent'] = df['Sent'].map(lambda x : x.replace(day=1))
```